# gnuTLS or SSL in cocoa

Tags: xcode, cocoa, ssl

I have a server I am trying t communicate to and it requires the usage of gnuTLS or SSL encryption. Is it possible for me to include the certificate in my cocoa application and use it for SSL communication and do I really need to use gnuTLS or is there any other way of using SSL connection from cocoa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To address the second question, it requires TLS or SSL. gnuTLS is just one implementation of TLS. If it's compliant, there is no way for the server to know which implementation you're using, and if it isn't compliant practically nobody will be able to interoperate with it, so why be the first?

Most people use OpenSSL from C or C++.

Comment: But if i was to use a certificate provided to be used, then would openSSL work?

Comment: @aayush sharma Of course. Otherwise RFC 2246 would be pointless.

Comment: thanks man. I`ll work with OpenSSL and ask anything if need be. I am still unsure of how to add my certificate in xcode itself and how to go about setting up the connection. But ill read up and work on it.